# jquety.text() unable to compare wih the given string

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-security

I have a spring boot app where I have implemented role-based authentication.
Once the end user is authenticated the menu from the database should load as per the role.
Once successfully authentication I'm extracting the role from the thymeleaf page the perform to load the menu.

Up to this works fine even if when I'm printing the role value like `alert("#hide").text()` it's alerting the role name.

To load the menu I should know which user is logged in so that the proper menu can be loaded.

That's why I'm extracting the value and comparing it like "admin", "user" etc.
But the comparison doesn't happen

### Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org">


<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>BSNL | CC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" 
          href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" 
          th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" 
          href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" 
          th:href="@{/css/menu.css}" />

</head>
<body>

    <div id="includedContent"></div>

    Logged in user: <b th:inline="text"  class="user" id="hide"> [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]] </b> 
    <input type="hidden" class="order-entry" id="ID" placeholder="" th:value="${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}"  value="${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}"/>

    <script th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.4.1.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/custom.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/home.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:**  `${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}` spring based code to see who logged in like admin, user or super admin.

### Home.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#includedContent").load("http://localhost:8080/BSNLCC-BackendWIthSecurity/home/"); 


    alert($("#hide").text());    //printing fine

    if($("#hide").text() == "null"){   //comparing not happening tried with ==== also
        alert(true);
      }
    /*
    if($("#rle").text() == "admin"){
        loadAdminMenu();
    }else if($("#ID").text() == "superadmin"){
        loadSuperAdminMenu();
    }

    function loadAdminMenu(){
        alert($("#rle").text());
        $.ajax({
            url: 'home/load/menu',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            data: {
                role: $("#rle").text()
            },
            cache: false,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }*/

});
```

Comment: Is your text actually meant to say "null" as a string? To compare with null you don't need the "" around null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One silly thing I've forgotten to trim the extracted value .trim() does the magic.